# What font is being used for the font-family 'heading' in this example?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I do not have a font named 'heading' installed, but my browser uses one with this name on this page: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/index.html . What is the actual font that is called 'heading' here?

This DOM: Programming JavaScript Applications is associated with such CSS: "font-family: "heading", Helvetica, sans-serif;"

Answer (score 0):

The font named 'heading' is defined using @font-face (i.e. "webfont") in the CSS file [default-6b113e470a1a8ec83000e32a1548bc3a.css](http://dwn0odqttrkhc.cloudfront.net/assets/default-6b113e470a1a8ec83000e32a1548bc3a.css). The actual font appears to be Gotham-Book.